# Django: how to create an object with only an auto field to get it's ID

Tags: django

I've a model Cart that has 2 fields, I'd rather change these 2 fields and keep only `date_added`.

Right now I cannot do it because I use the `cart_id` field to create the `Cart` object and extract it's `id`:

`cart_id` and `date_added`

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

In my view.py, I'm just creating the Cart object with the cart_id field as `Random`.

This only to create this object and after that, obtain it's id, to replace "Random" with the id of the Cart recently created. This is not DRY at all.

```
cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id="Random")
cart_id = cart.id
```

**How can I avoid this unnecessary step?**

Comment: Several questions: Why card_id is CharField? Assign random num as ids (What about collisions)?  Do you really need to create this by yourself, Django automatically creates `id` field for every table. How to avoid: Just filter by date and select the newest object.

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN card_id could be integer or whatever, I want to remove it. But I can't because currently I use it to Create the object and get it's id. How to filter if no object is created?

Comment: By default, Django creates a `pk` attribute for every new object. Once you remove `cart_id`, you can retrieve the `pk` using `cart.pk`. Having that said, I am not sure why you need a table with a single auto field column. For more info about `pk`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#the-pk-property

Comment: why do you need `cart_id`? if you are using `id`, I see no point of using `cart_id` (IMHO) :)

Comment: @Omar Gonzales Then if you wanna use cart_id as Primary Key you may add `primary_key=True` option. But for what?

Comment: @lsxliron becuase I'm filtering my cart_items based on the cart.id. but to create the cart I'm using the text "Random". I think it could be simplified, but how to create an object with only an auto field.

Comment: @FUNNYDMAN I don't want to use cart_id as PK, I want to delete this field. But then how to create an object with only an auto field? is possible?

Comment: You can also add the option ``unique=True`` to prevent collisions, but you have to try...catch when creating a new ``Cart``