# Django: cannot access Object in Admin Panel

Tags: django

When clicking the Object Cart or CartItem in the AdminPanel I'm getting:

> Error during template rendering
>
> In template D:\virtual_envs\stickers_gallito\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 0
>   **str** returned non-string (type int)

When querying these objects in shell, I'm getting:

```
>>> carts = Cart.objects.all()
>>> carts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers_gallito\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 247, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers_gallito\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 503, in __repr__
    return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

**models.py**:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is giving you a clue about what the problem is:

> TypeError: `__str__` returned non-string (type `int`)

You have defined a `__str__` method that is returning an integer ID, not a string, and hence the error. You need to coerce the value to a string:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

Note also that `self.id` is the auto-generated row ID in the database, and different from `self.cart_id`. You might want to use the latter instead if that is what you use to identify your carts.

Comment: ty. Refereing to `self.cart_id`, please, check this other question of mine:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54473915/django-how-to-create-an-object-with-only-an-auto-field-to-get-its-id